# Integration by part can also generate an invalid equation other than infinite expansion?

Tags: integration

The integral below can be solve by just using half angle formula. However if evaluate using integration by part, I will obtain $1=0$?

$\int(\sin(t)).(\sin(t)+\cos(t))$

letting $u=\sin(t)$ ,$dv=\sin(t)+\cos(t)$,$v=\sin(t)-\cos(t)$ and $du=\cos(t)$

$\int(\sin(t))(\sin(t)+\cos(t))$

$=\sin(t).(\sin(t)-\cos(t))-\int(\sin(t)-\cos(t)).(\cos(t))$-----equation(1)

letting $u=\cos(t)$,$dv=\sin(t)-\cos(t)$

$\int (\sin(t)-\cos(t))(\cos(t))=\cos(t).(-\cos(t)-\sin(t))-\int (\sin(t)).(cos(t)+sin(t))$----equation 2

substitute 2 into 1 yield

$\int(\sin(t))(\sin(t)+\cos(t))=\sin(t).(\sin(t)-\cos(t))-[(\cos(t).(-\cos(t)-\sin(t))-\int \sin(t)(\sin(t)+\cos(t))]$

If i evaluate correctly, my final equation will obtain

$0=(\sin(t))^2+(\cos(t))^2=1$

I only learnt that if choosing the incorrect pair of u and dv, it will lead to infinite expansion but it can also generate an invalid equation as above?

Comment: An integration by parts will have a hidden constant of integration.

Comment: Ah yes, totally forgot that

Comment: But the integral still cancel off leaving the constant= -1? feel like doesn't make sense

Comment: There is no *fixed* value for an indefinite integral (hence the $+C$). "Cancelling off" will result in the constant of integration resurfacing. It is quite confusing indeed.